# copy content of one DataTable to another without using clone or copy

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to copy the content from one datatable to another without copying or cloning the data structure. what is the best way to do this? 
I need to do it this way because I am given a datatable from a SQL server stored procedure and I cannot amend the given read only table. so I need recreate it without copying all the underlying structure.
I hope that makes sense.

Regards
Amarino

Comment: why would the original being read-only prevent you from copying? Are you getting an error when you do this? Note that cloning won't help you since you mention you want to keep the content (by which I assume you mean the row data, correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: `copy content...without copy` This makes no sense, and you have not provided any code.

Comment: I have added some code, I hope the question is a little clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy dataTable you have two options first one is copy or clone.
The second option is using foreach  or for loop to copy you can get any columns from dataTable

```
 int columnsize = dt.Columns.Count;
            foreach (DataRow X in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < columnsize; i++)
                {
                   // int bir = Convert.ToInt32(X[i]);
                   // you can set here your need dataTable

}


            }
// then here new dataTable you can assing to any datagridview.DataSource = newDataTable
```

but in the second case you should know ahead what data will come in which place to look this you can get any cell and assing it new DataTable

here is my using code

```
    DataTable dh1 = new DataTable("data1");

    dh1.Columns.Add("specification_name", typeof(string));
    dh1.Columns.Add("summalar", typeof(string));
    dh1.Columns.Add("address", typeof(string));
    dh1.Columns.Add("id1", typeof(int));
    dh1.Columns.Add("client_id", typeof(int));
    dh1.Columns.Add("stack_id", typeof(int));
    foreach (DataRow dd in dt.Rows) 
    {

        DataTable temp = new DataTable("temp");
        DataRow ttt = dh1.NewRow();

        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) 
        {

                ttt[0] = dd[1];
                ttt[1] = dd[2];
                ttt[2] = dd[3];
                ttt[3] = dd[4];
                ttt[4] = dd[5];
                ttt[5] = dd[6];
                break;


        }
        dh1.Rows.Add(ttt);





    }
```

Comment: do you not have to set up the new datatable columns correctly? as in make sure your datatable has the right number of columns and the columns are the right type?

Comment: every column should has proper type of  type in order to get value otherwise  it  won't work properly

Comment: I was looking to do something like this:                        DataTable lDT3 = new DataTable();

               foreach (DataColumn col in lDT2.Columns) {
                            lDT3.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
               }
                        //foreach (DataRow dr in lDT2.Rows) {
                        //    lDT3.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
                        //}
   for (int i = 1; i < lDT2.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
        for (int j = 0; j < lDT2.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
          lDT3.add(i,j) = lDT2.Rows[j][i].ToString();
    }
  }

Comment: I have edited my original question using your solution, hopefully you can see my intent more clearly and help me get to the point I want to get to.

Comment: your answer helped me get to the solution I needed. I have updated my question with the answer.

Comment: @Amar_H "I have updated my question with the answer"...no, the question should stay as a question. Accept the answer which solves the problem, or, if you believe you have a better solution, write your own answer - but in the Answers section, not in the original question - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to do something like this: The below solution works for me.

```
DataTable lDT2 = someMethod(); //populated with data from SomeMethod()
DataTable lDT3 = new DataTable();

lDT3.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
lDT3.Columns.Add("Name2", typeof(string));
foreach (DataColumn col in lDT2.Columns) {
    lDT3.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
}

foreach (DataRow dr in lDT2.Rows) {
   DataRow lDT3dr = lDT3.NewRow();
   for (int i = 0; i < lDT2.Columns.Count; i++) {
       if (i == 0) { lDT3dr[i] = "some info"; }
       if (i == 1) { lDT3dr[i] = "more info"; }
       lDT3dr[i+2] = dr[i];
    }
    lDT3.Rows.Add(lDT3dr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to copy the *data* but ignore the *schema*. You can do this by gathering data set from the source table then iterate through each row and insert it into the destination table.

This is a simple way to copy data from one table to another without any worry of keys or constraints. You will need to make sure your destination table can accept the data (it must be of the correct type or you must cast it to something acceptable).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use  DefaultView.ToTable().  This also allows you to pull DISTINCT values.  If you want all columns

```
var myNewTable = ExistingDataTable.DefaultView().ToTable();
```

If you wanted to limit for some criteria

```
var dv = ExistingDataTable.DefaultView();
dv.Filter = "SomeColumn = 'SomeValue'";
var myFilteredTable = dv.ToTable();
```